# matlab maximum of array with unknown dimension

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, max

I would like to compute the maximum and, more importantly, its coordinates of an N-by-N...by-N array, without specifying its dimensions.

For example, let's take:

```
A = [2 3];
B = [2 3; 3 4];
```

The function (lets call it `MAXI`) should return the following values for matrix `A`:

```
[fmax, coor] = MAXI(A)

fmax =
   3

coor =
   2
```

and for matrix `B`:

```
[fmax, coor] = MAXI(B)

fmax =
    4

coor=
    2   2
```

The main problem is not to develop a code that works for one class in particular, but to develop a code that as quickly as possible works for any input (with higher dimensions).

Comment: I've deleted my answer: read the documentation, especially the coverage of `max` and `ind2sub`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To find the absolute maximum, you'll have to convert your input matrix into a column vector first and find the linear index of the greatest element, and then convert it to the coordinates with [`ind2sub`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ind2sub.html). This can be a little bit tricky though, because `ind2sub` requires specifying a known number of output variables. For that purpose we can employ cell arrays and [comma-separated lists](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html?s_tid=doc_12b), like so:

```
[fmax, coor] = max(A(:));
if ismatrix(A)
    C = cell(1:ndims(A));
    [C{:}] = ind2sub(size(A), coor);
    coor = cell2mat(C);
end
```

EDIT: I've added an additional `if` statement that checks if the input is a matrix or a vector, and in case of the latter it returns the linear index itself as is.

In a function, it looks like so:

```
function [fmax, coor] = maxi(x)
    [fmax, coor] = max(A(:));
    if ismatrix(A)
        C = cell(1:ndims(A));
        [C{:}] = ind2sub(size(A), coor);
        coor = cell2mat(C);
    end
```

#### Example

```
A = [2 3; 3 4];
[fmax, coor] = maxi(A)

fmax =
    4

coor =
    2    2
```